# Check if a file was changed in during commit in git

Tags: git, version

Is there any git command which allows to check if a file was changed during last commit?

I'd like to check if a file which contains a version number was updated, otherwise the dev shall receive a warning not to release the software to an integration environment before a the version was bumped up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD | grep somefile.txt
```

This command assumes that you want to check whether the file `somefile.txt` changed in the last commit.  If you want to check whether `somefile.txt` changed between any two commits, then use

```
git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2 | grep somefile.txt
```

where `SHA1` and `SHA2` are the hashes of the two commits bounding the diff.

Comment: Be careful using this in scripts as you may get false positives. For example, `grep somefile.txt` matches `foo/somefile.txt` or `somefile.txt.gz` or even `somefileXtxt`.

Comment: Also note, if this is a first commit, and you are using it in a script - this will result `fatal: bad revision 'HEAD^'`. only after you have several commits - this diff will work

Answer (score 5):

```
[[ `git rev-parse @:path/to/file` = `git rev-parse @~:path/to/file` ]]
```

or as a function

```
head-changed-file () {
        set -- $(git rev-parse "@:$1" "@~:$1")
        [[ $1 != $2 ]]
}
```

and then you can `head-changed-file somefile.txt && echo okay it changed`

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff --quiet HEAD\^ HEAD -- path/to/file
```

exits with status code 1 if `path/to/file` is changed or removed in the last commit. Otherwise status code is 0.

Comment: Just note, if this is a first commit, and you are using it in a script - this will result `fatal: bad revision 'HEAD^'` only after you have several commits - this diff will work